# Grouped Buttons in html

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm having trouble with the grouped Buttons,let's say I'm having 5 buttons in html page. if I click the 3rd button buttons from 0 to 3 must changes its colour and function has to return 3 ,if I click 5 buttons from 0 to 5 have to change its colour and has to return 5 with the help of js

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you have tried post some code

Comment: Show us the code where you actually tried it yourself.

Comment: sounds like you are trying to make a 5 star rating system but in any case you have to first make an attempt, share your code/work and then we will be able to help and guide.

Comment: Please refer to [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and edit your question accordingly so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use scripts to get it done(some other easy methods may avail), here I have included jquery.

With jquery you can select all previous siblings using `prevAll()` and use `andSelf()` for selecting clicked button too. Check below snippet for simple example as you haven't provide any code.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).prevAll('.btn').andSelf().addClass('bg-red');
  $(this).nextAll('.btn').removeClass('bg-red');
  console.log($(this).data('value'));
});
```

```css
.bg-red{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="button 1" data-value="1">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="button 2" data-value="2">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="button 3" data-value="3">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="button 4" data-value="4">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="button 5" data-value="5">
```

Comment: This is working, yes, but Op did not tag this question with `jQuery`. So you should at least, tell that Op has to include a (whole) library for this (simple) job.